# CodeIgniter + Bootstrap integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications

My understanding of a framework like CodeIgniter is that it helps streamline the process of creating an app's front end via views and backend via the models and controllers.  Is it possible/easy/acceptable to use something such as Bootstrap or some other front end framework and integrate that with CodeIgniter?  Does it make sense when using a framework to build the front end separately from the back end then integrate, or build them at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap and codeigniter are awesome together. also if you have bootstrap code that gets repeated often you can make configs for them. for example if you have forms and are using codeigniter form helpers you can make configs that handle both the bootstrap code and the form field code. Using a quick example from the bootstrap page http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

```
// in your config
$config['btformgroup'] = '<div class="form-group">';

$config['emailfield'] = array(
'name' => 'email',
'class' => 'form-control', // Bootstrap specific 
'id' => 'exampleInputEmail1', 
'placeholder' = 'Enter email' );

// in your form   
echo $btformgroup . form_input($emailfield);

// etc etc - can also include set_value(), error messages, closing divs...
```

that way you can do your forms with pure php, and its very easy to change.

Answer (score 0):

yea sure you can easily integrate bootstrap or any front end framework like smarty templating engine with codeigniter.