# How to convert this HTML form to CodeIgniter form?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

How to convert this simple line to CodeIgniter Form
`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Submit</button>`

PS : I confused when I saw "i" tag in value of button, so I can't convert it to CI form

This is my PHP Code

```
<?php
$addProduct = array(                                                                                         
'value' => 'Add',
'class' => 'btn btn-success', 
);
echo form_submit($addProduct); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I look at it this way, you can have CI build the elements for you (which is perfectly fine) or (depending on your situation) just write out the markup.

Both have advantages/disadvantages. However, if you are on a team and another designer/developer does not understand what you are doing - or does not know CI, it might be worth your time to just write out the markup as "normal" html.

It may not be that glamours, but it is easier to maintain by the team.

Answer (score 0):

that is most probably font awesome and its probably being used with bootstrap code. 
bootstrap is great -- i use it in my forms and there are ways to combine it with codeigniter form helper. but if this is only for one or two forms -- just use the plain html it will be fine. otherwise if you have lots of forms and other bootstrap code to combine with them -- take a look at this for some quick ideas [CodeIgnitor + Bootstrap integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049886/codeignitor-bootstrap-integration/22052503#22052503)

Answer (score 0):

As someone said, `Bootstrap` and `Codeigniter forms` don't work well. My suggestion is that you could write html tags on your own without using form builder. While form builders take lesser time than writing HTML code, there is a possibility that getting used to it would make you forget HTML and styling. Furthermore, it also takes some processing for the Web Server to parse the Form Builder code into HTML. It's just my 2 cents and what I have always been upto.